# Generating a Library in C

Tags: c, gcc, header-files

I put all of the function declarations in a .h file and placed all of the functions in a unique .c file and also did the #include for the .h file in each one. However, when I try to compile with the -c switch so I get .o files for each one I get a message saying No such file or directory #include . When I take the #include header file out of each .c file I am able to obtain .o files, but then when I type ar rcs stephanstring.a *.o I get File format not recognized. Sorry for the bad explanation I'm just thoroughly confused.

Remember that we keep our function declarations in a header file, a .h file. Each of your functions should be in a separate .c file (e.g., you'll have strcmp_ign_case in a file called strcmp_ign_case.c file, the xerox function in xerox.c).

So you'll have:
    A collection of .c files:
        one for each function in the library
        a test program
    A single .h file, which includes the declarations for each of the functions in the library. This is #included by each of the .c files.
Generating the Library (5 points)
To create the library file, we use the ar command. The syntax is:
    ar rcs NameOfTheLibraryFileToCreate listOfFilesToIncludeInTheLibrary
Don't forget that you're including the binary files, i.e., the .o files, not your c source files.
So suppose you have all of your function .o files in a single directory, and you'd like to call your library file libstr2107.a, you'd type:
    ar rcs libstr2107.a *.o
To double-check, you can try:
    ar t libstr2107.a
if you see a list of your .o files, you've done it right.*

**This is my .h file which I saved as stephanstring.h and its placed in the same directory as all of the .c files. So in each .c file I did #include stephanstring.h **

```
int is_blank(char *s);
int find_idx(char *s, char c);
char *find_ptr(char *s, char c);
char *make_space(int width);
char *center(char *s, int width);
int begins_with_ignore_case(char *s, char *pre);
int ends_with_ignore_case(char *s, char *suff);
char *remove_chars(char *s1, char *s2);
int index_of_first_difference(char *s1, char *s2);
void lstrip(char *s);
void rstrip(char *s);
char *repeat(const char *s, int x);
char *slice(char *s, int b, int e);
int strcmp_ign_case(char *s1, char *s2);
char *ellipsize(char *s, int nw);
char *replace(char *s, char *pat, char *rep);
char **chop(char *s, char c);
```

Comment: Is this an assignment? If yes, this question is probably better directed to your instructor or TA, as they'll have much more context in which to understand the question. Also, they've probably encountered the same question dozens of times before and may be better able to help you understand the problem.

Comment: Additionally, the problem clearly lies with your `#include` statement, as you have deduced. It would help if you posted it along with some relevant information about your directory structure (assuming you still want help from us).

Comment: I was able to generate the .o files. Turns out I was using <stephanstring.h> when I should have been using " " instead of < >. But, I'm still encountering a problem when I do ar rcs stephanstring.a *.o  It says File format not recognized.